# Using a global variable to initialize an identity matrix not working

Tags: c++, c++17, eigen

I would like to use a global variable `n = 7` to initialize a `7x7` identity matrix, as shown in the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;

int n = 7;

int main()
{
        MatrixXd I = Matrix<double, n, n>::Identity();
        cout << I << endl;
}
```

When compiling, I get `error: the variable n is not usable in a constant expression`. Is there any way to use a global variable for initializing the identity matrix?

Comment: If `n` is not known at compile time: `MatrixXd::Identity(n, n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states, you need a compile time constant.

You can make `n` that by using `constexpr`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;

constexpr int n = 7;

int main()
{
        MatrixXd I = Matrix<double, n, n>::Identity();
        cout << I << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I need to do some research on "compile time constant".